# How to pass terraform code block as an input to module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to dynamically send the terraform code block from a file as an input to the module for creating AWS WAF v2 rules. Below is the sample rule statement:

```
      or_statement {
        statement {
          sqli_match_statement {
            field_to_match {
              single_header {
                name = "cookie"
              }
            }
            text_transformation {
              type     = "URL_DECODE"
              priority = 0
            }
          }
        }
        statement {
          sqli_match_statement {
            field_to_match {
              single_header {
                name = "authorization"
              }
            }
            text_transformation {
              type     = "HTML_ENTITY_DECODE"
              priority = 0
            }
          }
        }
```

Here I want to insert statements dynamically from a file like below

```
   statement {

         # Read contents from file and place here
         file("rulesfile")
  
        }
```

I tried above but it fails with the following error:

```
An argument or block definition is required here. To set an argument, use the equals sign "=" to introduce the argument
│ value.
```

I am using Terraform v1.0.4 and AWS provider version "3.54.0"

Comment: That's not possible in TF.

Comment: @Marcin Thank you for the details. Do you recommend any other alternative ways to achieve this?

Comment: Which tf resoruce are you trying to use? `aws_waf_rule`?

Comment: I am using `aws_wafv2_rule_group` and I want to send a statement block from a file or variable.

Comment: There's similar issue with terraform GCP Cloud Function v2, secret variables are required to be blocks. If there's no alternative to pass blocks to modules, it means that we can't create reusable cloud function v2 modules which take different secrets